# Getting Rails production to run on port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I'm trying to get my rails app to run in production mode but I've been having a bit of difficulty.

I'm using passenger with apache and am running Ubuntu 12.04.  I have my production database configured and created, and passenger set up.  Status is as follows:

```
$ rvmsudo passenger-status 
Version : 4.0.56
Date    : 2014-12-25 01:54:20 +0000
Instance: 7264
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
```

However when I run `rails server -e production`, it still listens on port 3000 see below:

```
$ rails server -e production
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-12-25 01:54:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-12-25 01:54:49] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [i686-linux]
[2014-12-25 01:54:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7459 port=3000
```

What might I be missing to get it to listens on port 80 in production mode?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `rails server -e production -p 80`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is how you have to start the server in production using Apache. Did you install apache-paassenger modules? and made changes in apache conf file?

First, the gem needs to be installed on the system:

```
gem install passenger
```

Before the Apache module is compiled, two dependency packages need to be installed as well:

```
apt-get install curl-devel httpd-devel
```

Use this command to start the apache installation: It will take some time

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Passenger will display some content after `Apache` installs:

Follow it up and make changes in **(/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)**

You will have to point to application public folder and restart the apache server follow with these sources closely.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-passenger

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

It helped when I did it for first time.