# Passenger cannot be initialized on RoR/Apache installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am trying to deploy a RoR app on MediaTemple(dv). I followed several guides in order to install passenger and configure my webserver too.

I am getting the following error on the apache log when I restart the server:

***[Mon Apr 20 02:14:16.823786 2015] [passenger:error] [pid 31196] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.6/buildout/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'PassengerRoot' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'PassengerRoot' directive, whichever is applicable.***

This is my site's configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.mydomain.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public
  PassengerAppRoot /var/www/mysite.com
  RailsEnv production

  <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>    

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

On my apache2.conf file: (at the end)

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.6/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.6
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/ruby
  PassengerDefaultUser root
</IfModule>
```

The module is also enabled:

```
a2enmod passenger
Module passenger already enabled
```

Any ideas? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: restarted apache server? what is your home page you mean?

Comment: I added more info to the problem

Comment: probably the package is broken, re-install `apache-paasenger` modules. check http://stackoverflow.com/a/27644318/2231236

Comment: I tried reinstalling the package and no go